# Is there away in PHP or JavaScript to click the accept cookie button if I visit a website from curl?

Tags: javascript, php

What I am trying to do is scrape an image from a website using curl. When I run my script on localhost it works perfectly and I get the scraped image, but when I run it on my online server on free shared host subdomain, the website is redirected to the link but there is a popup on the screen where it asks the user to accept the cookies and if I check the page source there is no meta tag which has the main image I am looking for. So I get 0 image back. So my question is if there is a way in JavaScript or PHP to click accept button and let the popup go away?

here is an image:
[image: here is an image] of what I see after I run the script on online server

and my curl code:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $_POST['url_link']);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo "<div>".$result."</div>";
// -------------- here i used htmlentities because i am trying many way to get it using this or another way of using file_get_content() but for now this is the way i am doing it
$htmlentities = htmlentities($result);

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$htmlDom = new DOMDocument();
$htmlDom->loadHTML($htmlentities);
```

Comment: but it did on my localhost by itself

Comment: Why not just pass the cookie?

Comment: @Yates what do you mean how can i do it ? i think i forgot to mention that i am visiting another website with curl for example http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/Techcrunch/~3/Prp5TTzUytc/

Comment: Find out what cookie they use to check if you have accepted their cookie wall or not then send it with your cURL request.

Comment: @Yates would that bypass the accept cookie popup ? i tried it did not work by choosing one of the cookies

Comment: Solution seems iframe ! but i need a way to access elements from the page in the iframe !

Comment: Hi - FYI scrap/scrapped means throw away - use scrape/scraped

Comment: @barny thanks for the information, "push or pull a hard or sharp implement across (a surface or object) so as to remove dirt or other matter" hehe yes it actually is hard to pull :D

Comment: You need a headless browser to do that. You can't do it purely in PHP

Comment: @dharman what do you headless ? I am trying to inject the cookie so maybe it would work

Comment: headless means that it has no user interface. You interact with the browser via code